# How to blur content behind of an overlay using java?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, overlay, blur

I have an layout that I can expose above other applications using Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE. But no matter how much I searched, I couldn't find a way to blur the content under this view to the user.

Here's what I wanted (I want to blur the behind content that I marked with red):

[image]

The code i use to display the layout:

```
public class OverlayManager2 {
    private final Context context;
    private final View mView;
    private final WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams;
    private final WindowManager mWindowManager;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public OverlayManager2(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pin_activity, null);

        mParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }



    public void open() {
        try {
            if (mView.getWindowToken() == null) {
                if (mView.getParent() == null) {
                    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mParams);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Some libraries I tried just blur a bitmap/image or content of a view object but they doesn't do exactly what i want to do or i failed (you can take a look if you want):

https://github.com/CameraKit/blurkit-android

https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView

https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

I saw that someone suggested to do this using opengl-es, but I couldn't find anything on how to do it.
I'm ready to merge my project with flutter if flutter can do that.

NOTE: I'm targetting SDK 29 (Android 10) so I can't use this: https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/window-blurs

Comment: There's no OpenGL on android. Only [tag:opengl-es].

Comment: Sorry for misspelling, I meant opengl-es of course. I'm fixing tag.

Comment: As far as I know you're out of luck. Unless you use window blurring api that you linked (which allows system window manager to take care of it) there just isn't a way to do a real blur without seeing what's behind your window and apps do not have that privilege.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware blurring of a view is not supported natively by any android version pre 12.  I believe blurring like that is more of an iOS feature. But by that being said you could fake it like some libraries do.

To do it yourself without a library you might be more successful to get it working like you want. Start by taking a screenshot of what is currently on the screen before showing the dialog. Convert the screenshot to a bitmap and blur it.
Add the bitmap to an `ImageView` which covers the entire screen. Show the `ImageView` and show the dialog and you should have a similar effect.

Things to consider, if you want it to look native you shouldn't blur the status bar on the top or the navigation bar on the bottom. If you want to have the blur look gradually animated use the alpha on the image view and animate it from 0 to 1 using a `ValueAnimator`. If you want everything on the screen to be blurred, you could potentially request the app to be full screen when you show the blurred image, but I think that could be a bit glitchy.

Another thing to consider with using blur on an image which is the same size of the image that you will display is that gaussian blur will create weird artefacts around the image which doesn't look perfect. You can get around that by having an image larger than what you will display and then crop it after blurring. But since you take a screenshot you don't have anything extra to play with.

Android isn't exactly known to handle blur well, so don't expect it to be butter smooth on every device. Personally, I agree that it looks cool, but I would probably decide to live without it. ;)

Comment: You're right I've been looking for a way to do this for a week and I'm really tired and bored of looking for this right now. For this part of my app I will just use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` and pass